# optimizing file writes with zlib?

Tags: c++, file-io, zlib

I profiled my app and apparently 37% of the time in my app is in ostream::write. Less then 7% was actually compressing it (deflate_slow is the function name it gave me).

How can i optimize file IO with zlib? should i write my own fopen/fwrite/fread/fclose wrapper? Is there a wrapper that exist? can i do something with the buffer size (i would like it large). What can i do to make writing faster?

Comment: I'm curious what your code looks like.

Comment: @Roland: A really really big tree. With 25k `new int` and `new string` which travels the tree and writes it into a file one at a time (among other data like typeid and flags in the int case)

Answer (score 0):

First, check that `ostream::write` is called inefficiently. Depending on your platform, you should use:

- Windows: `procmon.exe` (from the SysInternals Suite)
- Linux: `strace`
- Solaris: `ktruss`
- NetBSD: `ktrace`

Check whether there are many calls to `WriteFile` (Windows) or `write` (POSIX-like) which only write a few bytes, namely less than 100. If you cannot find these, it might not help writing a wrapper.

The above tools can also measure whether you lose time in the operating system's kernel or in the user code. That should give you a hint as to where you can improve performance.

Comment: this is really not helpful. i wrote my own memory code wrapping around fopen/write and the app ran runtime split in half.